# To implement a facade DB table or not? [pics]

Tags: schema

Does it make sense to normalize a schema with tables that only serve the purpose of logically separating parts of a system? Below are 2 example schema with what I am talking about. (sorry about the titles being hard to read) One with the "superfluous" selection criteria table and the other without it. What makes more sense? why? Thanks!

[image]

[image]